# Validation problems with displaying message in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I have made some validation on my form, and after all, I have some div in my input field with the id of this input field.

I would like to print errors in those divs. That means: if 
some input is missing I want in html, before that input, set errorMessage in that div.

The problem is that library jquery.validate.js write error betwen radio elements and that doesn't look nice.

Any idea about how to realize this?

For Example (HTML):

```html
 <tr>
    <td>
     <label for='question2'>Some question</label>
</td>
<td valign='top'>
     <input type='radio' name='question2' value='1'/>Answer1<br />
     <input type='radio' name='question2' value='2'/>Answer2<br />
     <input type='radio' name='question2' value='3'/>Answer3<br />
     <input type='radio' name='question2' value='4'/>Answer4<br />
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>
     <div id='question23Error'></div>

           //I WOULD LIKE TO PUT HERE MESSAGE FOR ALL INPUT INDIVIDUALLY

</td>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#surveyData').validate({

errorContainer: '#errorbox',   //THIS CODE IS ONLY USEFUL IF YOU HAVE A FORM WITH 5 INPUT'S, IF YOU HAVE 30 INPUTS THAN IT BRINGS ALL ERRORS AT BEGGINING OF THE FORM AND IT ISN'T TRANSPARENT
errorLabelContainer: '#errorbox ul', //
wrapper: 'li', //

    rules: {
        surname : { 
            required:true,
            minlength: 2, 
        }, 
        question1: { 
            required:true,
            minlength: 2, 
        }, 

        question2 : { 
            required: true, 
            }, 

        question3 : {
            required: true, 
        },  
    messages: { 
        surname : {
            required: 'Enter surname!' , 
            minlength: 'Surname should be longer!', 
        }, 
        question1: {
            required: 'Enter your opinion.', 
            minlength: 'Your opinion should be longer', 
        }, 
        question2: { 
            required: 'Please choose radio button.', 
        }, 
        question3: { 
            required: 'Please choose radio button', 
        }, 
    },

    };
});
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

```
errorPlacement:function(error, element)
        {
            if($(element).attr("name")=="question2")
            {
                $(element).parent().append(error);
            }else
            {
            $(error).insertAfter(element);
            }   
        },
```

Comment: As you can seee here: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html                                                             The error message is belove radioGrups, but my eror is printing after first radio value inside radio grups. So how could I solv this?

Comment: IS there any parameter to add in meessages or rules which will set errors in those divs?

Comment: replace the line **$(element).parent().eq(2).append(error);** to  **$(element).parent().append(error);** .

Comment: @ RobertP: i edited the above code and try it